# Date comparison in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angularjs, I would like to show either "before", "during" or "after" in {{here}} as shown below:

```
 <td md-cell>{{here}}</td>
 <td md-cell>{{a.StartDate}} ～ {{a.EndDate}}</td>
```

The StartDate and EndDate are retrieved from SQL database and both are working without any problems.

I have written something like the code below trying compare the date, I'm not sure if meets angularjs' grammar and I would like to have the return values shown in {{here}}.

```
vm.checkStatus = function (var StartDate, var EndDate){

        var currentDate = new Date();
        if (currentDate < StartDate)
            return "Before";
        else if (currentDate >=StartDate && currentDate <= EndDate)
            return "During";
        else if (currentDate > EndDate)
            return "After";
        else
            return "Invalid";

    }
```

How can I connect them together?

Comment: Change {{here}} to call the function you defined. Similar to {{vm.checkStatus(a.StartDate, a.EndDate)}}

Comment: My usual sidenote here, I will always be disconcerted by the number of people who will still start to learn Angular 1 in 2025, when Angular 2 was released two years ago (September 2016), and the current version is Angular 6

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either change your function call to :

```
 <td md-cell>{{vm.checkStatus(a.StartDate, a.EndDate)}}</td>
 <td md-cell>{{a.StartDate}} ～ {{a.EndDate}}</td>
```

**Or** your function to :

```
vm.checkStatus = function (var StartDate, var EndDate){

    var currentDate = new Date();
    if (currentDate < StartDate)
        this.here =  "Before";
    else if (currentDate >=StartDate && currentDate <= EndDate)
        this.here = "During";
    else if (currentDate > EndDate)
        this.here = "After";
    else
        this.here = "Invalid";

}
```

And a var declaration / initialization

```
public var here = "Invalid"
```